Unable to solve dtype issue using UnslothAI fine tuning for Llama 3.1 8B model
I am new to fine tuning LLMs and I have been trying to run the notebooks provided by UnSlothAI. For this question, I am running the code for fine-tuning LLaMa 3.1 8B model as posted here
This colab notebook uses a huggingface dataset on which the LLM is fine tuned.
alpaca_prompt = """Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input that provides further context. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.


### Instruction:
{}

### Input:
{}

### Response:
{}"""

EOS_TOKEN = tokenizer.eos_token # Must add EOS_TOKEN
def formatting_prompts_func(examples):
    instructions = examples["instruction"]
    inputs       = examples["input"]
    outputs      = examples["output"]
    texts = []
    for instruction, input, output in zip(instructions, inputs, outputs):
        # Must add EOS_TOKEN, otherwise your generation will go on forever!
        text = alpaca_prompt.format(instruction, input, output) + EOS_TOKEN
        texts.append(text)
    return { "text" : texts, }
pass

from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("yahma/alpaca-cleaned", split = "train")
dataset = dataset.map(formatting_prompts_func, batched = True,)

I want to use my own data, so I have introduced this small change
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
from datasets import Dataset
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt', quiet=True)

def load_model():
    model_name = "mrm8488/t5-base-finetuned-question-generation-ap"
    tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
    return tokenizer, model

def generate_question(sentence, tokenizer, model):
    input_text = "generate question: " + sentence
    input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    outputs = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=64, num_return_sequences=1)
    question = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    question = question.replace("question: ", "", 1).strip()
    question = question[0].upper() + question[1:]
    return question

def process_paragraph(paragraph, tokenizer, model):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
    questions = [generate_question(sentence, tokenizer, model) for sentence in sentences]
    return sentences, questions

def create_dataset(sentences, questions):
    return Dataset.from_dict({
        'output': sentences,
        'input': [''] * len(sentences),
        'instruction': questions
    })

# Load the model
tokenizer, model = load_model()

# Example usage
paragraph = """Whales are magnificent marine mammals. These colossal creatures inhabit oceans worldwide. 
Whales are divided into two main groups: baleen whales and toothed whales. 
Baleen whales have a filtering system in their mouths. 
Toothed whales, including dolphins and porpoises, have teeth for catching prey. 
Whales are known for their intelligence and complex social structures. 
These giants of the sea vary greatly in size. 
The blue whale is the largest animal ever known to have existed. 
Conservation efforts are crucial for protecting whale populations."""

sentences, questions = process_paragraph(paragraph, tokenizer, model)

# Create the dataset
dataset_whales = create_dataset(sentences, questions)

# Print information about the dataset
print(dataset_whales)
print("\nFirst few examples:")
print(dataset_whales[:3])
dataset_whales = dataset_whales.map(formatting_prompts_func, batched = True,)

The model was able to train properly but when I run the following inference code
# alpaca_prompt = Copied from above
FastLanguageModel.for_inference(model) # Enable native 2x faster inference
inputs = tokenizer(
[
    alpaca_prompt.format(
        "Continue the fibonnaci sequence.", # instruction
        "1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8", # input
        "", # output - leave this blank for generation!
    )
], return_tensors = "pt").to("cuda")

outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens = 64, use_cache = True)
tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs)

It gives me the error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-64c50bf8aa34> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 ], return_tensors = "pt").to("cuda")
     11 
---> 12 outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens = 64, use_cache = True)
     13 tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
    113     def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
    114         with ctx_factory():
--> 115             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    116 
    117     return decorate_context

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/unsloth/models/llama.py in _fast_generate(*args, **kwargs)
   1191 
   1192         # Autocasted
-> 1193         with torch.autocast(device_type = device_type, dtype = dtype):
   1194             output = generate(*args, **kwargs)
   1195         pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/amp/autocast_mode.py in __enter__(self)
    363             self.prev = torch.is_autocast_enabled()
    364             self.prev_fastdtype = torch.get_autocast_gpu_dtype()
--> 365             torch.set_autocast_gpu_dtype(self.fast_dtype)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    366             torch.set_autocast_enabled(self._enabled)
    367             torch.autocast_increment_nesting()

TypeError: dtype must be a torch.dtype (got str)

What changes should I make for the code to work? Thanks in advance!
